# How I set up an Web Api end point hosted directly on Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, asp.net-core-webapi

I would like to expose an http server on my xamarin forms app to expose data outside the phone, is it possible ? For example, an endpoind which returns log file inside phone. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. We are using EmbedIO.
Take a look at this [github repo](https://github.com/unosquare/embedio).

You can create your webserver like (basic example)

```
var server = new WebServer(o => o
                    .WithMode(HttpListenerMode.EmbedIO))
                    .WithLocalSessionManager()
                    .WithWebApi("/api", m => m.WithController(() => new YourController()));


public class YourController : WebApiController
{
   [Route(HttpVerbs.Get, "/test")]
   public Task<string> Get()
   {
      return Task.FromResult("test");
   }
}
```

Ofc you need to know device IP address. Then you can set it for example

```
_server = new WebServer(o => o
                    .WithUrlPrefixes($"http://yourIp:8088")
...
```